# load tile map into libgdx in android

Tags: android, libgdx, tiled

I tried to load tile map into libgdx. I followed so many different tutorials and built number of them from scratch. I used "Tiled" to create tmx file and used Tileset png from android-> asset folder. I also set working directory to asset folder.

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {

    private MarioBros game;
    private Hud hud;
    private OrthographicCamera gamecam;
    private Viewport gamePort;

    private TmxMapLoader mapLoader;
    private TiledMap map;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;

    public PlayScreen(MarioBros game) {
        this.game = game;
        gamecam = new OrthographicCamera();
        gamePort = new FitViewport(MarioBros.V_WIDTH, MarioBros.V_HEIGHT, gamecam);
        hud = new Hud(game.batch);

        mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
        map = mapLoader.load("level1.tmx");
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
        gamecam.position.set(gamePort.getScreenWidth()/2, gamePort.getScreenHeight()/2, 0);
    }
    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    public void handleInput(float dt) {
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched())
            gamecam.position.x += 100 * dt;

    }
    public void update(float dt) {
        handleInput(dt);
        gamecam.update();
        renderer.setView(gamecam);
    }
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        update(delta);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        renderer.render();

        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
        hud.stage.draw();


    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        gamePort.update(width, height);

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

When I run the program, this error message keeps appearing:

```
> Task :desktop:DesktopLauncher.main()
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Unrecognised compression (zstd) for TMX Layer Data
    at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.BaseTmxMapLoader.getTileIds(BaseTmxMapLoader.java:495)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.BaseTmxMapLoader.loadTileLayer(BaseTmxMapLoader.java:213)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.BaseTmxMapLoader.loadLayer(BaseTmxMapLoader.java:172)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.BaseTmxMapLoader.loadTiledMap(BaseTmxMapLoader.java:162)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:81)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:59)
    at com.mygdx.mariobros.Screens.PlayScreen.<init>(PlayScreen.java:35)
    at com.mygdx.mariobros.MarioBros.create(MarioBros.java:19)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:150)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:127)

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the compression of the `.tmx` file. Like the stacktrace says, the compression **zstd** is not recognized by the libGDX loader (although this seems to be the default compression in Tiled).

To change the compression type:

- open the `.tmx` file using Tiled
- in the menu bar click on `Map` -> `Map Properties...`
- in the map properties, that appears on the left, change the value of `Tile Layer Format`
- In the dropdown you can change the compression to a value different from `Base64 (zStandard compressed)`

In my project I just tried `Base64 (uncompressed)`, `Base64 (gzip compressed)` and `Base64 (zlib compressed)`, which all seemed to be working in libGDX (Version 1.9.10)